# Remove php extension remove then I add / in url

Tags: .htaccess

[www.example.com/about.php](http://www.example.com/about.php)
url i want to change this url
[www.example.com/about/](http://www.example.com/about/)

I want to .php extension remove then I add / in url

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example.com/demo/khushal/$1/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
</IfModule>

Comment: Kindly do add these rules in your question, thank you.